# Estimating parameters for probit multiplied by something

Tags: stata, probit

Assume you have a model of the form $y = x_1\Phi(\beta_0 + \beta_2x_2 +\ldots+ \beta_nx_n)+u$ where $y_i\in(0,x_{1i}]$ and $\Phi$ is the probit function.

How can we estimate $\beta$s in e.g. Stata?

Comment: I am a little confused about this model since I don't know what error distribution would be sensible - you'd need to do something strange, or transform the response, to keep the $y \in (0,x_1]$ constraint. Anyway, I doubt this model is pre-implemented in any software package so you'll probably have to "make your own". If you know the distribution of $u$, you can calculate the (log) density of $y|x_1,...,x_n$ and maximize it as a function of $\beta_0, ...., \beta_n$ to get the maximum likelihood estimate.

Comment: maybe it's more helpful to think about it in a standard probit sense. let $y^*=y/x_1$. the model $y^*=\Phi(\beta_0+\beta_2x_2+\ldots+\beta_nx_n)+u$ is more natural in this case, as $y^*\in(0,1]$. we can estimate this using probit in stata. instead, im concerned with the case where instead we are concerned with separating the numerator and denominator of $y^*$...hope that helps

Comment: in the model i posit, $E(u|x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$.

Comment: The usual probit model arises when you assume some underlying latent variable follows a usual Gaussian-error regression model and that latent variable is binned into categories. When there are only two categories and the threshold at $0$ separates them, you have the usual binary probit regression model. With more thresholds (and therefore more categories) you have the ordinal probit model. I'm failing to see the connect between that and this. What am I missing?

Comment: the dependent variable in this case is not binary. it is a proportion

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure what this model buys you. You may want to look into beta regression and, if you have the number of "successes" and "failures" that produced the proportion, then you could use binomial regression (such as probit).

Comment: i realize this model wont buy me much, but i am still curious how the estimated parameters differ from one model to the other and so i would like to be able to model this. thank you for your help though!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For proportions as the outcome, take a look at Chris Baum's [Stata Tip #63](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0147). Another related approach is user-written `betafit` from SSC. For many of these, the two extremes of 0 and 1 will be problematic. The glm method discussed by Baum is a notable exception.

Personally, I would avoid going the nonlinear least squares route with `nl`, but that may be feasible. In any case, you can do that in the following way (toy example):

```
use http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo, clear
nl (honors = math * normal({_cons} + {read}*read +{female}*female)), robust
```

One issue for comparisons is that ordinary probit estimates will not exactly match nl, even without using math as $x_1$:

```
. probit honors read female, nolog

Probit regression                                 Number of obs   =        200
                                                  LR chi2(2)      =      61.31
                                                  Prob > chi2     =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -84.990569                       Pseudo R2       =     0.2651

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      honors |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        read |   .0856048   .0130065     6.58   0.000     .0601126    .1110971
      female |   .6340312   .2300876     2.76   0.006     .1830678    1.084995
       _cons |  -5.672047   .7798024    -7.27   0.000    -7.200432   -4.143662
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. nl (honors = normal({_cons} + {read}*read +{female}*female)), robust nolog
(obs = 200)

Nonlinear regression                                 Number of obs =       200
                                                     R-squared     =    0.4734
                                                     Adj R-squared =    0.4653
                                                     Root MSE      =   .376412
                                                     Res. dev.     =  173.7243

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
      honors |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      /_cons |  -5.277098   .8583791    -6.15   0.000    -6.969889   -3.584307
       /read |   .0782903   .0138473     5.65   0.000     .0509824    .1055982
     /female |   .6814231   .2597361     2.62   0.009      .169203    1.193643
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I'd be interested in you elaborating as to why you don't like `nl`. That would be the first thing I would try.

Comment: Non-linear estimation outside toy examples always makes me nervous. With the probit, the log-likelihood is globally concave, so numerical methods should quickly converge to a unique optimum. I am worried that multiplying by $x_1$, a variable that we have no information on, may mess things up here.

Comment: Dimitriy, I would say that these are different enough models to diverge in small samples ($n=200$ ain't a terrific sample size). `nl` is assumes that the errors are homoskedastic around the mean (given by the probit), while `probit` is smarter and knows that they aren't. I am actually more worried about the standard errors here -- I would argue that you need to use `nl, robust` standard errors here (and in pretty much any other `nl` analysis, I dare say).